# PHP Header Location with parameter. Delete and back to previous list

Tags: php, header, location, dreamweaver, dynamic-pages

I have a list of rows with their respective links to go to "remove.php" and run `"DELETE FROM"` and so remove each row separately. 
This list is on a dynamic page `details.php?recordID=123`

How could I set the `header(location: ...)` value including the details.php parameters? 
I want to go back (Reliably) to the source list after deleting the row.

```
  $deleteGoTo = "details.php?recordID=123";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: @Michael , If I put a valid page to `$deleteGoTo` there is no problem. Eg: `$deleteGoTo = "details.php"`
So, everything works perfect.
But I need to go to a dynamically generated list (page) containing parameters. Example: www.domain.com/details.php?recordID=123
At the moment I don't know how to pass the parameter `?recordID=123`
I hope I have explained well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the parse_url and parse_str functions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php